# What are the stretches in the Blogilates "Journey to Splits" program?

Tags: stretching, flexibility, splits

I was looking for a resource on achieving the splits, and stumbled on the [Blogilates #JourneyToSplits](https://www.blogilates.com/30-days-30-stretches-to-splits-journeytosplits/) program.

The stretches included in the program are these (details in the linked blog post):

[image: Blogilates Journey to splits]

My problem is that as far as I have managed to find, this image is the only reference for what the stretches included are, and some of those photos are from a poorly-chosen angle. In particular, I'm having trouble telling what the difference between 16 and 17 is, and the knee discomfort I got from trying to replicate them suggests that I should look up some cues on how to safely perform them. And, to effectively Google them, I'd need to know their names.

So, *what are these 30 stretches called*?

Please pardon the breadth of this one question, it is either this or post 30 near-identical questions.

Comment: Not a complete answer, but the difference between #16 and #17 is which leg is forward. In 16, the right leg is forward (The back leg), and in 17, the left (near) leg is forward.

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to do the front splits, this poster is a terrible way to do it.   This poster is just a random collection of yoga poses.  If you want to get into the splits, look up Kit Laughlins videos.  Unfortunately, his splits tutorial is behind a paywall.  Or, check out https://www.gotrom.com .  Again, you will need to get past a paywall.  You get what you pay for.

As a disclaimer, I have not paid the fee to get behind either of these paywalls, but it appears that the people who produced the above content have at least put some thought into their work, instead of throwing random yoga poses into a poster.

Let me explain why this poster is so bad.  As an example, look at stretch 24.  It will be very difficult for most people to reach their foot. Most people will need a progression of less aggressive stretches to get to the point where they can reach their foot. Unfortunately, this poster doesn't have such a progression.   Progression is the key to getting to the splits or any fitness goal.

Also, keep in mind that the model is this poster has probably been hyperflexible since she was a child.  These stretches work for her.  If you have average flexibility, then your path to the splits is going to be completely different from her practice.  Kit Laughlin says that if you are trying to get flexible as an adult, never take instruction from someone who has been flexible their whole life.

Finally, I stretch every day, and have been for years, but I stretch to feel better, and I couldn't care less about doing the splits.  Why is it important for you to do the splits?  Will you be competing in gymnastics?